# Generalized Linear Mixed Modeling questions

Tags: logistic, repeated-measures, multinomial-distribution

I have a dataset with assessments taken at different visits: baseline (visit=1), and then various post-baseline visits (2, 3, 4), and the following variables:

**DISEASE** - the outcome, is an ordinal variable with 4 levels (1=normal, 2=mild, 3=moderate, 4=severe);
**BSL_DISEASE** - the baseline value of DISEASE;
**AGEGRP** - the age group the participants are in;
**VISIT** - the visit (1 is baseline, 2 is Day 10 post-baseline, 3 is Day 30 post-baseline and 4 is Day 90 post-baseline);
**BNP** - lab measurement of BNP (continuous);
**SEVERITY** - binary variable derived based on DISEASE, i.e., if DISEASE in (0,1) then SEVERITY=0 (not severe), else SEVERITY=1 (severe);

Objective of my exercise problem is to investigate the correlation between the lab measurement BNP (as predictor) and the DISEASE (as outcome). I basically want to look at change in serum concentrations of the BNP as markers for change in DISEASE. Since this is a longitudinal study, with repeated measurements taken on the same subjects and ordinal multinomial outcome, I am thinking of exploring the correlation between BNP and DISEASE from baseline (visit=1) to Day 30 (visit=4) by using repeated measures logistic regression, implemented via PROC GLIMMIX. So I have fit the following model:

```
data have;
input ID$ DISEASE$ AGEGRP$ VISIT$ BNP SEVERITY$ BSL_DISEASE$;
datalines;
a001 1 1 1 1997.02 0 1
a001 1 1 2 1275.52 0 1
a001 4 1 3 180.23 1 1
a001 2 1 4 735.91 0 1
a002 1 2 1 454.16 0 1
a002 1 2 3 1776.52 0 1
a002 3 2 4 73.15 1 1
a003 1 2 1 1700.26 0 1
a003 3 2 2 1621.32 1 1
a003 2 2 4 850.65 0 1
a004 2 3 1 1963.25 0 2
a004 2 3 2 544.87 0 2
a004 4 3 3 768.54 1 2
a004 2 3 4 780.16 0 2
a005 1 2 1 655.24 0 1
a005 2 2 4 722.14 0 1
a006 1 1 1 1472.06 0 1
a006 1 1 4 749.78 0 1
a007 2 1 1 848.88 0 2
a007 2 1 2 1482.78 0 2
a007 3 1 4 735.26 1 2
a008 1 1 1 1752.35 0 1
a008 1 1 2 1698.82 0 1
a008 3 1 3 1871.25 1 1
a008 4 1 4 587.35 1 1
a009 1 3 1 1549.89 0 1
a009 3 3 3 785.52 1 1
a009 1 3 4 384.72 0 1
a010 3 3 1 1211.95 1 3
a010 3 3 4 1596.38 1 3
a011 4 1 1 1785.45 1 4
a011 4 1 4 644.12 1 4
a012 3 3 1 798.28 1 3
a012 3 3 2 742.69 1 3
a012 3 3 3 1423.59 1 3
a012 3 3 4 1089.47 1 3
;
run;
proc glimmix data=have noclprint; 
class ID VISIT (ref='1'); 
model DISEASE (event='1')= BNP VISIT/ dist=mult link=clogit solution; 
random VISIT/subject=ID residual type=CS; 
random INT/subject=ID type=CS;
output out=FITDAT pred(ilink noblup)=predprob; 
NLOPTIONS tech=NRRIDG Maxiter=1000; 
run;
```

But I get an error message that "R side random effects are not supported for the multinomial" so I deleted the random VISIT statement and it converges now but my questions are:

1. Is this model the correct one to fit to the data in order to address my objective?
2. Don't I need a random VISIT statement? My understanding is that I need to impose some sort of covariance structure on visit, otherwise we're just assuming that the values at the various visits are not correlated which I'm not sure is accurate?

Any guidance/code/suggestions would be very helpful at this point, as I am bit stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: It's been a long time since I used GLIMMIX but I would look at a paper by Kathleen Kiernan  (from SAS) which has lots of examples and troubleshooting ideas.

Comment: Hi Peter! Thanks, I've already read some of Kiernan's papers, including the very helpful one on  PROC GLIMMIX ("Insights into Using the GLIMMIX Procedure
to Model Categorical Outcomes with Random Effects") but unfortunately, I wasn't able to get the answers I needed. I was hoping someone might be able to chim in on whether the model I'm using is well suited to answering the specific research question or if the data I have is even enough to attempt any modeling and get any meaningful results (I suspect not?)